# PHP mySQL ~Echoed table and columns not displaying properly

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$Table = $_POST['Table'];

$mysqli = new mysqli
("LoginSec.db.11321798.hostedresource.com", "LoginSec", "aaAA11!!", "LoginSec");
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES");
while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() ){
$table = $row[0];
$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $Table LIMIT 0,12");
if($result1) {
echo '<table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="20" class="db-table">';
$column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
echo '<tr>';
while($row3 = $column->fetch_row() ) {
echo '<th>'.$row3[0].'</th>';



}
echo '</tr>';
while($row2 = $result1->fetch_row() ) {
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach($row2 as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<td style="padding-top:10px;padding.bottom:10px;">',$value,'</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table><br />';
}
}
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Also I have posted a URL to a pic of the issue, Please take a look and if you have any ideas please let me know. The cell padding all have been set properly.

Comment: postimg org/image/49hrwwcmb/

Comment: postimg org/image/axje53147/

Comment: `$column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");` should be `$column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $Table");`

Comment: My code was wrong and I updated it but I'm still having the same issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't:

```
<td style="padding-top:10px;padding.bottom:10px;">
```

be

```
<td style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
```

?

"padding.bottom" is not valid CSS.

Comment: Also $table and $Table are being used inter-changablely